# MithrilJS: Routing a component inside top level component

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I just started reading about Mithril. Fascinating..
Just one thing that puzzles me after first read.

How can I route one component inside another (top-level component)? I mean, how do I emulate angulars ng-view or embers outlet?

I understand that I can get m.route to attach components to any dom node. 
But how can I render say top level component App, which generates m("#view") among other things, and then all other routable components go inside App's #view div? Is this possible? Otherwise I have to repeatedly include header and footer with every route transition to a subcomponent, right? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Otherwise I have to repeatedly include header and footer with every route transition to a subcomponent, right? Am I missing something?

I don't think you're missing anything. Mithril has as little magic as possible, so it's hard to miss things. Yet it's still somehow more convenient than frameworks with magic.

I simply wrap my views in a template function. I'm a lazy guy, but even I don't mind doing this because it's flexible and not confusing.

http://codepen.io/farzher/pen/vOjjEB

```
function viewTemplate(content) {
  return function() {return [
    m('#header', [
      'my site',
      m('a', {config:m.route, href:'/'}, 'home'),
      m('a', {config:m.route, href:'/1'}, 'page 1'),
      m('a', {config:m.route, href:'/2'}, 'page 2'),
    ]),
    m('hr'),

    m("#view", content),

    m('#footer', 'copyright my site'),
  ]}
}

component1 = {
  view: viewTemplate([
    m('h1', 'component 1 page')
  ])
}

component2 = {
  view: viewTemplate([
    m('h1', 'component 2 page')
  ])
}

m.route(document.body, '/', {
  '/': {view: viewTemplate()},
  '/1': component1,
  '/2': component2,
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found Leo's suggestion I posted above which I prefer for the top outer layout. But your method is good too as an option. I think I'd use it if any further sub layering  is required. I'll give you the tick as your answer  helped me understand how people solve this kind of  problems. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with on of the Leo's suggestions I found googling around.

I can only have "one-layer" wrap and no named outlets with this solution but it works and does the job for now.

At the end of the day, Angular has only one ng-view and people get by somehow.

So this is the outer component.

```
var Layout = {
  controller(subcomp) {
    this.own = {
      slide: false
      };
    this.subctrl = new subcomp.controller();
    this.subview = subcomp.view;
  },
  view(ctrl) {
    return bubble(ctrl.own, ctrl.subview(ctrl.subctrl));
  },
  wrap(routes) {
    var map = {};
    Object.keys(routes).map((r) => {
      map[r] = {
        controller() {
          return new Layout.controller(routes[r]);
        },
        view: Layout.view
      };
    });
    return map;
  }
};
```

This is the outer view where you insert your component.

```
function bubble(vm, subview) {
  return m("main", [
    m("#outlet",[ subview ])
  ]);
}
```

And then you route all your subcomponents inside the layout.

```
m.route.mode = "pathname";
m.route(document.body, "/articles/create", Layout.wrap({
  "/articles/create": CreateArticle
}));
```

Hope this helps someone in the same situation.

Comment: That's a very good idea too. I've actually seen that route wrapping concept turned into a plugin https://github.com/gitter-badger/moria checkout the usage section at the bottom, pretty cool

Comment: Small syntax note: shouldn't the `Layout` component's methods be like `wrap: function(routes) {` instead of `wrap(routes) {`?

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23 This is ES6 syntax. It is perfectly ok.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several solutions:

1. With `m.component` for route handler -
   http://jsfiddle.net/0xwq00zm/1/
2. With internal method of the `App` component, that wraps the inner component. This is somewhat better, cause I'm able to pass aplication state to other components - http://jsfiddle.net/0xwq00zm/11/
3. With simple external function, that wraps the inner component with
   other elements - http://jsfiddle.net/0xwq00zm/12/

More or less complex - with all of them I have the feeling that the apps redraws itself, and not only the inner component.

Simply select all the elements - `Ctrl+A` in the result pane in JsFiddle - and then navigate. It's virtual DOM and it shouldn't re-render everything, but with all solutions above - it happens.

(I tried also with `context.retain = true;` on some parts, but still after a few navigations I get to a point where nothing gets selected.)

========

Hope these variants help someone ... but also - I'll be happy to see solution of the total re-rendering.